# Is there a regex to match Facebook urls that contain videos or photos?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, facebook, oembed

Is there a regex to match facebook url that have photos and/or videos? From what I can see such urls vary considerably. For example:
`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=827947030561502`

`https://www.facebook.com/idfonline/photos/a.250335824989295.62131.125249070831305/827806643908874/?type=1`

The first contains a video and the 2nd a photo.

I have a regex for FB posts: `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/(?:(?:\w\.)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[\w\-\.]*\/)*([\w\-\.]*)`

That regex works fine when I embed a post like `https://www.facebook.com/hnbot/posts/703129179742366` but not for things that have photo or video. So is it possible to have a regex for those posts with video or photos? This is all for the purposes of embedding FB posts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Yeah already know the world will end etc etc etc but thanks anyways

Comment: post samples of all possible urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex handles almost all facebook urls:

`"((http:\/\/(www\.facebook\.com\/photo\.php.*|www\.facebook\.com\/video\/video\.php.*|www\.facebook\.com\/.*\/posts\/.*|fb\.me\/.*|www\.facebook\.com\/.*\/photos\/.*))|(https:\/\/(www\.facebook\.com\/photo\.php.*|www\.facebook\.com\/video\/video\.php.*|www\.facebook\.com\/.*\/posts\/.*|fb\.me\/.*|www\.facebook\.com\/.*\/photos\/.*)))"`

It just doesnt handle something like `https://www.facebook.com/idfonline/photos/a.250335824989295.62131.125249070831305/827806643908874/?type=1`